# How to make sure there is no duplicate data on model's keys?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This is my user model:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    watched: [{ type: String}],
    watchLater: [{ type: String}],
  },
  { timestamps: true },
)
```

there is `watched` and `watchLater` array which contains **strings**. When I add a **string** to `watched` I want to remove or make sure there is no same **string** on `watchLater` and vice versa. What's the best approach for this? Do I have to query both keys separately, compare, and write back to the database or there is some other way?

Comment: Use `$addToSet` during update.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm already doing but here should be no duplicates not just in the array itself but also between `watched` and `watchLater` arrays

Comment: Does the answer work? Or do you need something else?

Comment: I'm not sure how does that code work. Here's more specific post, please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53511795/how-do-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-models-array

Comment: In that question you want to remove id from the array and here you want to restrict duplicate `id` from adding. Both are different.

Comment: I want the same thing. Sorry if my explanation is confusing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the criteria in query part

```
db.collection.update(
  { watched: { $ne: string } watchedLater: { $ne:string }}, 
  { $push: { watched: string }}
)
```