# How do I remove a specific item from model's array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my user model with `watched` and `watchLater` arrays:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    watched: [{ type: Number }],
    watchLater: [{ type: Number }],
  },
  { timestamps: true },
)
```

I have this function where I want to remove **id** from `watchLater` and add to `watched`:

```
  async addToWatched(id) {
    const _id = this.getUserId()
    return await this.store.User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id },
      // remove id from watchLater and add to watched,
      { new: true },
    )
  }
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been reading docs a bit. This seems to work:

```
return await this.store.User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  { _id },
  // remove id from watchLater and add to watched,
  { $pull: { watchLater: id }, $addToSet: { watched: id } },
  { new: true },
)
```